# MODx Revolution Login Addon: Cant Login or Logout with Login form or Logout Link

Tags: authentication, logout, modx, add-on

I encountered a Problem with MODx Revolution today. I used the Add-On Login the first time. So excuse if this is some of a stupid Error.

I've setup two contexts (Babel) and the latest version of the login plugin (and some other stuff). MODx version 2.2.6.

So what I did is: Created a Resource Group and gave it Load, view and list rights to each context on Member 9999 and for the anonymous group just Load. This all seems to work.

I can login into the manager with correct credentials and navigate to the protected site. As expected i can see the content that is protected. I logout and the login form apears. All correct till here.

When i  navigate to the login form and try to login with incorrect credentials I also get a error message as expected.
Now: When I try to login with correct credentials (the same I use for the manager login) it doesnt come up with any kind of error but it looks like I'm not logged in correctly.

Symtoms:
I can see the login count in the MySQL tables for this specific user. No logins were incorrect and the user is not blocked.
When i login in the manager and navigate to the protected site, hit the logout button, I get redirected back to the set &loginResourceId and do not get logged out. Still logged in.

I checked the MODx Log and there was nothing pointing to this error. I can't check the apache log because I'm on a shared hosting. The error_log file doesnt show anything suspiscious aswell.

My question: what have I done? I checked all the references to the login page from the logout link, checked all permissions and still no result.

Maybe someone had the same issue or anything like that. After hours of google and try and error, I'm kinda stuck.

EDIT

[[!Login?
            &loginTpl=`lgnLoginTpl`
            &logoutTpl=`lgnLogoutTpl`
            &errTpl=`lgnErrTpl`
            &loginResourceId=`156`
            &logoutResourceId=`4`
        ]]

thanks already for your suggestions
rootless

Answer (score 0):

Modx does behave oddly when you are logged in as an administrator in the manager context and then try to log in as a different user in the web context. I use a different browser altogether for the manager when I am testing access controls - something to do with the manager credentials having full access to both contexts no matter what, not 100% exactly why. but try using a different browser for the manager and different credentials for the privileged user in the web context [i.e. not the same manager credentials] and see if that changes the behavior at all.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. tried from different machine in different network and different user, still the same behaviour.

Comment: long shot - but try calling all your login/logout snippets uncached.

Comment: not yet the final result.. does not work either. as i did not know what cache you mean exactly, i cleared on a fresh linux install all the caches from the client side. Cleared and disabled all MODx caches and manually deleted all files in core/cache..

Comment: when you are inserting/calling a snippet in your templates/pages putting a ! in front of it tells modx not to cache that part of the resource - it will always get processed. I think you would always want to call your login scripts uncached. ex: [[!Login? &whatever=]] like wise you can use it when outputting variables & placeholders as well, [[!+myPlaceholder]] [[!+myVariable]]

Comment: thanks again for your reply. this is what i am doing, calling all snippets with a !. i updated my the actual question with my code used.